# What is the proper widget hierarchy of a Flutter app containing a splash screen, login screen, and home page?

Tags: flutter, structure

I have a Flutter app currently like this:

```
[root]
 > Pheonix
   > UserInheritedWidget
     > MaterialApp
       > Splashscreen
         > LoginScreen
         > HomePage
```

It's arranged like this as I am using [`flutter_screenutil`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) by placing `ScreenUtil.init` in the first line of the first `build` function of my widget tree, i.e. my `Splashcreen`.

That's all fine and good, but now android users will be directed back to `Splashscreen` if they tap the native Android "back" button while in `LoginPage` or `HomePage`, which I don't want.

I see that I can prevent this by wrapping `LoginPage` or `HomePage` with `WillPopScope`, but it feels more like a workaround for an improper app structure.

This is also reinforced by the `home` parameter of `MaterialApp`, which I currently have set to `Splashscreen`, which feels... wrong.

I tried to use `Navigator.pushReplacement` instead of `Navigator.push` at Splashscreen to get this structure instead:

```
[root]
 > Pheonix
   > UserInheritedWidget
     > MaterialApp
       > Splashscreen
       > LoginScreen
       > HomePage
```

This does prevent users from going back to `Splashscreen` with the "back" button. However, it causes this error with `[ScreenUtil.setWidth]` inside `HomePage` (i.e. when I call something like `5.w`):

> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

In conclusion, what's the app structure that properly implements a splashscreen, login screen, and home screen, while properly implementing `ScreenUtil`, *and* properly uses the `home:` (and maybe `routes:`?) parameter of `MaterialApp`?

Comment: Please share a detailed description of this error along with the code `_CastError` to evaluate the error.

Comment: I'd recommend to change the `home` of your `MaterialApp` dynamically, for example with a `provider`. Depending on your conditions, the home will be one of the three widgets at any given moment.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Interesting, I could try that out. Is that the common practice or recommended method for managing routes?

Comment: @NathanTew I can't say if it is common practice but I am using this approach to set the `home` route for apps that need to distinguish between logged in and not logged in status. It is only about `home` route, the rest of the routes are managed with `Navigator`. You need to close all routes if the user logs out.